# Using curl to get Tomcat and PGSQL service status

Tags: curl

I have a server that is running postgresql and tomcat. I would like to run a curl command that returns the status of these two services if they're up or down (preferably in JSON format), is that possible? If so, can you please let me know?

Thanks

Comment: Trying to use Nagios for this now. I found out this server is on a restricted network, so we can only ssh tunnel to it. Can we somehow check the status of pgsql via ssh tunnel?

Comment: Running this on my localhost where Nagios is installed: ssh -f user@192.168.1.5 -L 5000:192.168.1.5:5432 -N

Then on localhost, run ./check_tcp -H 192.168.1.5 -p 5000 -v